# class to handle concurrent data insertion in java

Tags: java, insert, java.util.concurrent

There will be 500+ threads concurrently uploading an unique object to a bucket all the time.

In this case, which data structure/class i should use to implement bucket in java.

FYI:

I tried using ArrayList, Vector, ConcurrentHashMap, ArrayBlockingQueue, LinkedBlockingQueue.

ArrayList fails as it is not thread safe.
  Vector consumes more time for insertion. (as the wait time to get the monitor lock is high)

... finally, I used ArrayBlockingQueue which sounds good on comparing others.

Suggest me if any other good class/ data structure exists for this case.

Comment: Do you need a set or a list? I.e., should the data structure automatically filter out duplicate elements? This is a key distinction of data structures and important to answer your question.

Comment: there won't be duplicate elements. and to be specific i need a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contention will be very high, so you may want to look at lock-free wait-free implementations available or - to keep it simple - use ConcurrentHashMap.

Lock striping is the key benefit here, so that for read operations you have no lock, for write operations you only lock a subset of existing buckets, and you lock the entire hashtable only for rehashing.

You can find a bit more here:

[Performance ConcurrentHashmap vs HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378310/performance-concurrenthashmap-vs-hashmap)

[Java Hashtable many accesses problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235297/java-hashtable-many-accesses-problem)

Answer (score 1):

You are taking the right decision to measure the performance.

In general a LinkedBlockingQueue performs better for concurrent access than ArrayListBlockingQueue so I would definitely try that.

Comment: In my case, insertion is only concurrent. Accessing or polling value out will be taken care by a single thread.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you want to do after adding stuff, or during adding stuff. You first need to think about that.

In the most simple case imaginable, maybe you want to iterate the objects later in no particular order. If that's the case, ConcurrentLinkedQueue will probably be the best in terms of insertion performance.